# How to call GetDeviceInformation method in SUDS?

Tags: python, wsdl, suds, onvif

Actually encountered such a problem: when I try to execute the method `GetDeviceInformation` like `client.service.GetDeviceInformation()` I get the following error: `Type not found: '(IPAddressFilter, http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd, )'`. Is i possible somehow to fix this problem as it occurs on the request generation step.